# Meteor Callback Codrops Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, meteor

I am new to Meteor (and javascript) and trying to figure out how to integrate the Codrops sidebar menu found here: [Codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/05/12/morphing-buttons-concept/). I have created a "sidebar" template and all scripts are loading correctly.

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="morph-button morph-button-sidebar morph-button-fixed">
    <button type="button"><span class="icon icon-cog">Settings Menu</span></button>
    <div class="morph-content">
        <div>
            <div class="content-style-sidebar">
                <span class="icon icon-close">Close the overlay</span>
                <h2>Settings</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="icon icon-camera" href="#">Default filters</a></li>
                    <li><a class="icon icon-server" href="#">Storage Use</a></li>
                    <li><a class="icon icon-heart" href="#">Favorites</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- morph-button -->
```

And this javascript code for the Meteor callback:

```
Template.sidebar.events({
    'click .morph-button': function () {
        $('.morph-content').transition();
    }
});

Template.sidebar.rendered = function () {
    $('.morph-content').transition();
};
```

I am having trouble understanding how this works. I am getting funny results. Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble finding much documentation on the menu you are talking about. So I am going to take a more JS approach to answering this question.

Under events you are attaching transition() to $('.morph-content'), which you have already done when the DOM was rendered. I would assume that the one doesn't belong. You may just need to attach it under rendered, and the included JS may attach everything else it needs to the DOM(i.e. when you add $('.date').datepicker() to an HTML element.